# Tomcat Apache ServletException Output Encoding

Tags: java, apache, security, tomcat, xss

I have a strange issue. In Tomcat 4.0.6, if I raise a default javax.servlet.ServletException(message) where message contains dangerous HTML such as an XSS attack alert(1), it's reflected unencoded back to the user on the Server 500 Exception Report page.

However in Tomcat 6.0.37, the same application raises the same javax.servlet.ServletException(Message) the message is returned with encoded HTML entities such as '<>' which is safe.

I cannot find any documentation on the default behaviour for Tomcat 6 vs. Tomcat 4. Where is this documented or noted? Is it dangerous to assume that not all Tomcat versions will properly sanitize user behaviour? Reference (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletException.html)

Can anyone clarify what's going on here?

Comment: You should really no longer use such old Tomcat version because of security risks! Actual version (today) are 7.x, 8.x and 9.x.